# How do I pull a specific amount of values each time from a python list?

Tags: python, list, iterator

If I have a list like the following:

```
list = ['example1' , 'example2' , 'example3' , 'example4', 'example5','example6']
```

How would I go about pulling three values at a time? I want to then create two separate lists like the following

```
new_list1 = ['example1' , 'example2' , 'example3']
new_list2 = ['example4' , 'example5' ,'example6']
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do not do list = "something". list is a built-in function and you are overwriting it. Be aware of those functions. Regards.

Comment: If the problem is just "split at index 3 into two things", the duplicates are overkill; all you need is `new_list1 = orig_list[:3]`, `new_list2 = orig_list[3:]`.